# PHP regular expression string starting with certain characters and followed by digits

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression to validate a code. The rules are as follows:

- It starts with a B or J or 28
- Total length of the string must be either 7 or 13 characters (including starting characters)
- The characters following the starting characters must be all digits

Can anyone help me with this ? Thanks

I tried something like

```
$pattern = "/^((J|B|28)([0-9])({7}|{13})?/i";
```

But it doesn't seem to work :\

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$pattern = "/^(?=(.{7}|.{13})$)(B|J|28)\d+$/";
```

Comment: I always had problems with these regular expressions.. I don't know when I will start to learn using them :) good job Mike, I've also tested it and it works +1

Comment: Change it to `/^(?=(.{7}|.{13})$)(B|J|28)\d+$/` and will work

Comment: Vote up for speed; but would rather see the edit explaining the subpatterns, delimiter use, back reference, etc... That's what contributes to getting DjMike (and everyone else) to the next level :)

On a side note, his is case insensitive, yours isn't.

Comment: @Daniel true, my understanding of regular expressions is horrible :\

Comment: Have to admit clever use of the conditional check here, you can further simplify by changing `?=(.{7}|.{13}` to `?=(.{7,13}`

Comment: @kjetilh. No, that would allow 7 or 13 chars or any number in between.

Comment: Bah I see now, either 7 or 13 characters long :)

Comment: DjMike I'm sure @MikeM will find the time to get an edit in there... :x If not you can always check the PCRE syntax on the manual :)

Answer (score 1):

First use the following regular expression to match the pattern. It will capture the first identifier in the first group and the following digits in the second group.

```
<?php 
$pattern = "/^(B|J|28)([0-9]+)$/i"; 
?>
```

Then run `strlen()` to validate the length. Regular expressions are not a good tool to validate variable lengths across groups.

```
<?php 
$hasValidLength = strlen( $str ) === 7 || strlen( $str ) === 13; 
?>
```

Comment: He said total length must be between 7-13 including starting characters

Comment: i'll check. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Wops. Then he should rather do a `strlen()` check after running the regular expression.

Comment: It doesn't match this for example: J100027872577

Comment: I think the idea (**of the question**) is to have a single regular expression to match against the code.

Comment: Sure, but I think his ultimate goal is to validate the code regardless of the means. My regex also captures the two groups separately which may or may not be useful to the DjMike.